# Python order of execution with classes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to understand how Python2.7.10 is behaving the way it is in my script.

Here is what I have:

```
import sys, getopt
import socket
import re
import pprint

class New_VM(object):
    ''' Class to validate options and arguments being passed in. '''
    def __init__(self, argv):
        # Accept command line options and arguments being passed in to the script.
        # Options are being held in the opts data structure.
        # Arguments are being held in the args data structure.
        try:
            opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv, "hn:m:p:d:s:r:t:",["hostname=","eth0=","eth1=","defaultgw=","subnet=","route-eth0=", "rt_tables="])
            #pprint.pprint(opts)
            print(opts[0])
            #sys.exit(2)
        # Raise exception and die if invalid option is passed in.
        except getopt.GetoptError:
            print 'Invalid script syntax:'
            print 'buildNetworkFile.py -n <hostname> -m <eth0_ip> -p <eth1_ip> -d <default_gw> -s <subnet> -r <route-eth0 file> -t <rt_tables file>'
            sys.exit(2)


        # Validate correct number of options/arguments are being passed in and take action accordingly.
        for opt, arg in opts:
            # Display help if -h option is passed or die if less than 5 options passed.
            if opt == '-h' or len(opts) < 5:
            #if opt == '-h':
                print 'Please use syntax below to run script.'
                print 'Script requires 5 arguments to be passed in.'
                print 'buildNetworkFile.py -n <hostname> -m <eth0_ip> -p <eth1_ip> -d <default_gw> -s <subnet> -r <route-eth0 file> -t <rt_tables file>'
                sys.exit(2)
                #break
            # Catch the hostname being passed in.
            elif opt in ("-n", "--hostname"):
                    self._hostname = arg
            # Validate management IP being passed in.
            elif opt in ("-m", "--eth0"):
                try:
                    self._eth0 = arg
                    socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET, self._eth0)
                except AttributeError:
                    try: 
                        self._eth0 = arg
                        socket.inet_aton(self._eth0)
                    except socket.error:
                        print 'Socket error when validating management(eth0) IP..' 
                        #return False
                except socket.error:
                        print 'Invalid managment(eth0) IP. Please check your IP and try again.'
                        sys.exit(2)
            # Validate public IP being passed in.
            elif opt in ("-p", "--eth1"):
                try:
                    self._eth1 = arg
                    socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET, self._eth1)
                except AttributeError:
                    try: 
                        self._eth1 = arg
                        socket.inet_aton(self._eth1)
                    except socket.error:
                        print 'Socket error when validating public(eht1) IP..' 
                        #return False
                except socket.error:
                        print 'Invalid public(eth1) IP. Please check your IP and try again.'
                        sys.exit(2)
            # Validate default gateway IP being passed in.
            elif opt in ("-d", "--defaultgw"):
                try:
                    self._dg = arg
                    socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET, self._dg)
                except AttributeError:
                    try: 
                        self._dg = arg
                        socket.inet_aton(self._dg)
                    except socket.error:
                        print 'Socket error when validating defautl gateway IP..' 
                        #return False
                except socket.error:
                        print 'Invalid Default Gateway IP. Please check your IP and try again.'
                        sys.exit(2)
            elif opt in ("-s", "--subnet"):
            # Validate subnet IP being passed in.
                try:
                    self._subnet = arg
                    socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET, self._subnet)
                except AttributeError:
                    try: 
                        self._subnet = arg
                        socket.inet_aton(self._subnet)
                    except socket.error:
                        print 'Socket error when validating subnet IP..' 
                        #return False
                except socket.error:
                        print 'Invalid Subnet IP. Please check your IP and try again.'
                        sys.exit(2)
            # Check if route-eth0 file is being passed in. 
            elif opt in ("-r", "--route-eth0"):
                self._routeEth0 = arg
                try:
                    with open(self._routeEth0) as text_file:
                        with open('routeEth0.txt', mode='w') as out_file:
                            lines = text_file.readlines()
                            out_file.writelines(lines)
                except:
                    print('The route-eth0 file you specified was not found. Please try again.\n')
                    sys.exit(2)
            # Check if rt_tables file is being passed in.
            elif opt in ("-t", "--rt_tables"):
                self._rtTables = arg
                try:
                    with open(self._rtTables) as text_file:
                        with open('rt_tables.txt', mode='w') as out_file:
                            lines = text_file.readlines()
                            out_file.writelines(lines)
                except:
                    print('The rt_tables file you specified was not found. Please try again.\n')
                    sys.exit(2)
        # If no arguments are passed die. If opts[0] is equal to the script name (buildNetworkFile.py) then die.
        try:
            arg1 = opts[0]
            sys.exit(2)
        except IndexError as e:
            print 'Not enough arguments passed. Please run script with -h option for syntax information.'
            sys.exit(2)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'New_VM\'s'

    @property
    def hostname(self):
        return self._hostname
    @property
    def managementIP(self):
        return self._eth0
    @property
    def publicIP(self):
        return self._eth1
    @property
    def defaultGW(self):
        return self._dg
    @property
    def subnet(self):
        return self._subnet

class Configure_Files(New_VM):
    #def __init__(self):
    #'''Special Init Class for Configure NewtorkFiles Class'''
    #return None

    @property
    def hostname(self):
    return self._hostname

    # Class vars
    domain = 'blah.net'
    networking = 'yes'
    networking_ipv6 = 'yes'
    nozerconf = 'yes'
    gateway = 'self._dg'
    ipv6_defaultgw='2001:578:15:4801:'
    ipv6_defaultdev='eth1'
    hwaddr=''
    mgtInterface='eth0'
    pubInterface='eth1'
    dns1='1.1.1.1'
    dns2='1.1.1.1'
    mgtDomain='blah2.net'
    onBootYes='yes'
    onBootNo='no'
    userCtlYes='yes'
    userCtlNo='No'
    bootProtocol='static'
    peerDnsYes='yes'
    peerDnsNo='No'
    ipv6InitYes='yes'
    ipv6InitNo='no'
    ipv6Addr='2001:578:115:4820:'
    # Ask user for Management Network IP and validate it.
    mgtNetwork = raw_input("Please enter the Management Network IP.\n")
    try:
        socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET, mgtNetwork)
    except AttributeError:
        try:
            socket.inet_aton(mgtNetwork)
        except socket.error:
            print 'Socket error when validating subnet IP..'
    except socket.error:
        print 'Invalid Management Network IP. Please check your IP and try again.'
        sys.exit(2)
    # Ask user for Public Network IP and validate it.
    pubNetwork = raw_input("Please enter the Public Network IP.\n")
    try:
        socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET, pubNetwork)
    except AttributeError:
        try:
            socket.inet_aton(pubNetwork)
        except socket.error:
            print 'Socket error when validating subnet IP..'
    except socket.error:
        print 'Invalid Public Network IP. Please check your IP and try again.'
        sys.exit(2)


    @property
    def provisionEth0(self):
        return self._eth0
        #return domain

    def network(self):
        ''' Build the contents for /etc/sysconfig/newtork file '''
    '''print 'HOSTNAME=%s' % self._hostname
    print 'DOMAIN=%s' % Configure_Files.domain
    print 'NETWORKING=%s' % Configure_Files.networking
    print 'NETWORKING_IPV6=%s' % Configure_Files.networking_ipv6
    print 'GATEWAY=%s' % self._dg'''
        dg2 = re.sub('[.]',':', self._dg) # Replacing '.' with ':' so it can be appended to IPV6_DEFAULTGW var
        '''print 'IPV6_DEFAULTGW=%s%s' % (Configure_Files.ipv6_defaultgw, dg2)
    print 'IPV6_DEFAULTDEV=%s' % Configure_Files.ipv6_defaultdev'''
        with open('network.txt', mode='w') as out_file:
        out_file.writelines('HOSTNAME=%s \n' % self._hostname)
        out_file.writelines('DOMAIN=%s \n' % Configure_Files.domain)
        out_file.writelines('NETWORKING=%s \n' % Configure_Files.networking)
        out_file.writelines('NETWORKING_IPV6=%s \n' % Configure_Files.networking_ipv6)
        out_file.writelines('GATEWAY=%s \n' % self._dg)
            out_file.writelines('IPV6_DEFAULTGW=%s%s \n' % (Configure_Files.ipv6_defaultgw, dg2))
        out_file.writelines('IPV6_DEFAULTDEV=%s \n' % Configure_Files.ipv6_defaultdev)

    def eth0Config(self):
        '''Build the contents for /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0'''
        # Grab the HWADDR from the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 file
        try:
            with open('/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0') as text_file:
                for line in text_file:
                    try:
                        match = re.search(r'HWADDR=(.*)', line, re.M|re.I)
                        Configure_Files.hwaddr=match.group(1)
                        #print(match.group(1))
                        break
                    except:
                        print('There was no \'HWADDR\' string found in the /etc/syconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 file.')
                        print('Setting HWADDR to blank')
                        break
                        #sys.exit(2)
        except IOError as e:
            print ('/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 not found: ', e)
            sys.exit(2)
        '''print 'HWADDR=%s' % (Configure_Files.hwaddr)
        print 'NAME=%s' % (Configure_Files.mgtInterface)
        print 'DNS1=%s' % (Configure_Files.dns1)
        print 'DNS2=%s' % (Configure_Files.dns2)
    print 'DOMAIN=%s' % (Configure_Files.mgtDomain)
    print 'ONBOOT=%s' % (Configure_Files.onBootYes)
    print 'USERCTL=%s' % (Configure_Files.userCtlNo)
    print 'BOOTPROTO=%s' % (Configure_Files.bootProtocol)
    print 'PEERDNS=%s' % (Configure_Files.peerDnsNo)
        print 'IPADDR=%s' % (self._eth0)
        print 'NETMASK=%s' % (self.subnet)
        print 'NETWORK=%s' % (Configure_Files.mgtNetwork)
        print 'IPV6INIT=%s' % (Configure_Files.ipv6InitYes)
        print 'GATEWAY=%s' % (self._dg)'''
        ipv6addr2 = re.sub('[.]',':', self._eth0) # Replacing '.' with ':' so it can be appended to IPV6ADDR var
        #print 'IPV6ADDR=%s%s' % (Configure_Files.ipv6Addr, ipv6addr2)
        ifcfg_string = '''check_link_down () {\n return 1;\n}''' 
        with open('ifcfg-eth0.txt', mode='w') as out_file:
            out_file.writelines('HWADDR=%s \n' % Configure_Files.hwaddr)
            out_file.writelines('NAME=%s \n' % Configure_Files.mgtInterface)
            out_file.writelines('DNS1=%s \n' % Configure_Files.dns1)
            out_file.writelines('DNS2=%s \n' % Configure_Files.dns2)
            out_file.writelines('DOMAIN=%s \n' % Configure_Files.mgtDomain)
            out_file.writelines('ONBOOT=%s \n' % Configure_Files.onBootYes)
            out_file.writelines('USERCTL=%s \n' % Configure_Files.userCtlNo)
        out_file.writelines('BOOTPROTO=%s \n' % Configure_Files.bootProtocol)
            out_file.writelines('PEERDNS=%s \n' % Configure_Files.peerDnsNo)
            out_file.writelines('IPADDR=%s \n' % self._eth0)
            out_file.writelines('NETMASK=%s \n' % self.subnet)
            out_file.writelines('NETWORK=%s \n' % Configure_Files.mgtNetwork)
            out_file.writelines('IPV6INIT=%s \n' % Configure_Files.ipv6InitYes)
            out_file.writelines('GATEWAY=%s \n' % self._dg)
            out_file.writelines('IPV6ADDR=%s%s \n' % (Configure_Files.ipv6Addr, ipv6addr2))
            out_file.writelines(ifcfg_string)

    def eth1Config(self):
        '''Build the contents for /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1'''
        # Grab the HWADDR from the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1 file
        try:
            with open('/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1') as text_file:
                for line in text_file:
                    try:
                        match = re.search(r'HWADDR=(.*)', line, re.M|re.I)
                        Configure_Files.hwaddr=match.group(1)
                        #print(match.group(1))
                        break
                    except:
                        print('There was no \'HWADDR\' string found in the /etc/syconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1 file.')
                        print('Setting HWADDR to blank')
                        break
                        #sys.exit(2)
        except IOError as e:
                        print ('/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1 not found: ', e)
                        sys.exit(2)

        '''print 'HWADDR=%s' % (Configure_Files.hwaddr)
        print 'NAME=%s' % (Configure_Files.mgtInterface)
        print 'DNS1=%s' % (Configure_Files.dns1)
        print 'DNS2=%s' % (Configure_Files.dns2)
    print 'DOMAIN=%s' % (Configure_Files.domain)
    print 'ONBOOT=%s' % (Configure_Files.onBootYes)
    print 'USERCTL=%s' % (Configure_Files.userCtlNo)
    print 'BOOTPROTO=%s' % (Configure_Files.bootProtocol)
    print 'PEERDNS=%s' % (Configure_Files.peerDnsNo)
        print 'IPADDR=%s' % (self._eth1)
        print 'NETMASK=%s' % (self.subnet)
        print 'NETWORK=%s' % (Configure_Files.pubNetwork)
        #print 'IPV6INIT=%s' % (Configure_Files.ipv6InitYes)
        print 'GATEWAY=%s' % (self._dg)'''
        ifcfg_string = '''check_link_down () {\n return 1;\n}''' 
        with open('ifcfg-eth1.txt', mode='w') as out_file:
            out_file.writelines('HWADDR=%s \n' % Configure_Files.hwaddr)
            out_file.writelines('NAME=%s \n' % Configure_Files.mgtInterface)
            out_file.writelines('DNS1=%s \n' % Configure_Files.dns1)
            out_file.writelines('DNS2=%s \n' % Configure_Files.dns2)
            out_file.writelines('DOMAIN=%s \n' % Configure_Files.domain)
            out_file.writelines('ONBOOT=%s \n' % Configure_Files.onBootYes)
            out_file.writelines('USERCTL=%s \n' % Configure_Files.userCtlNo)
        out_file.writelines('BOOTPROTO=%s \n' % Configure_Files.bootProtocol)
            out_file.writelines('PEERDNS=%s \n' % Configure_Files.peerDnsNo)
            out_file.writelines('IPADDR=%s \n' % self._eth0)
            out_file.writelines('NETMASK=%s \n' % self.subnet)
            out_file.writelines('NETWORK=%s \n' % Configure_Files.pubNetwork)
            out_file.writelines('GATEWAY=%s \n' % self._dg)
            out_file.writelines(ifcfg_string)

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    server = New_VM(sys.argv[1:]) # Get everything after the script name
    #print str(server) + ' hostname is ' + str(server.hostname)
    #print str(server) + ' management IP is ' + str(server.managementIP)
    #print str(server) + ' public IP is ' + str(server.publicIP)
    #print str(server) + ' Default GW IP is ' + str(server.defaultGW)
    #print str(server) + ' Subnet IP is ' + str(server.subnet)
    #buildFile = Configure_Files(sys.argv[1:])
    #buildFile.network()
    #buildFile.eth0Config()
```

Ok going to give this another shot.

I am requesting the user to enter in raw data inside the Configure_Files Class. However, even though I'm not calling the Configure_Files Class from main, I'm still being prompted to enter raw data.

When I run the script with -h option (python buildNetworkFile.py -h) I immediately get prompted for the raw data and once I enter the raw data (which is just 2 IP addresses) I get displayed the help info.

If I take out the raw input code from the Configure_Class then I no longer get prompted for raw input when running the script with the '-h' option.

I think I'm messing up on exception handling somewhere but can't figure out where. But that's just me guessing...

Comment: Learn to use a debugger, it will pay off for you

Comment: Please post real code.

Comment: I've added the code if anyone want to take a stab at it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explanation, it seems your code only "dies" after asking for the raw input because only after it tries to write that data to the file does the program realize the file does not exist, and then the script fails.

Try this to properly check if a file exists:

```
import os.path
os.path.exists(file_path)
```

The statement `os.path.exists(file_path)` returns `True` if a file or directory exists, else it returns `False`.